# Loop in Python to find the max value of every destiny

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am fairly new in python. I am working with the nycflights13 df.

My goal is to determine the most common and least common origin for every destiny.

```
+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| destiny | most_common_origin | max_count | least_common_origin |  min_count |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| MIA     | LGA                |      5781 | EWR                 |       2633 |
+---------+--------------------+-----------+---------------------+------------+
```

I managed to do it for one destiny but I´m having trouble in the loop and also the binding the rows because sometimes I get a series.

My working example

```
from nycflights13 import flights

flights_to_MIA = flights[flights['dest']=='MIA']
flights_to_MIA.groupby(flights_to_MIA['origin']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

Note that I used size and then reset.index to make it a df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check `agg` + `value_counts`

```
s=df.groupby('dest').agg(most_common_origin=('origin',lambda x : x.mode()[0]),
                              max_count=('origin',lambda x : x.value_counts().sort_values().iloc[-1]),
                              least_common_origin=('origin',lambda x : x.value_counts().sort_values().iloc[[0]].index),
                              min_count=('origin',lambda x : x.value_counts().sort_values().iloc[0]))
```

Comment: "Function names must be unique, found multiple named origin"
It seems i can´t use multiple functions inside agg, maybe a dictionary?

Comment: @EvilEmi what is your pandas version ?

Comment: It seems   0.25.3 I have no idea why, I´ll upgrade

Comment: It almost worked, the least common origin and most common is a number not the actual airport

Comment: It seems both mix and max counts are the same

Comment: @EvilEmi I am checking it

Comment: you´re a beast Thanks!